# Object keys to string based on value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

Good evening,

Within React state I have the following object:
`... .modals{search: true, social: false, menu: true, login: false}`

The Boolean values change depending on whether certain modals are active. I would like to extract the active modals based on `true` and return them into a `data-modal` property within my react component - so that I can use them for conditional CSS.

As an example the result of above would be `data-modal="search menu"`. In other words, those keys that have a positive value are added to the string.

I've played around with a few things; join, map, foreach etc, but can't find a combination that works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const modals = {search: true, social: true, menu: true, login: false}

let active = ''
for(key in modals) {
  if(modals[key]) active += ' ' + key;
}
```

Now you can pass to `data-modal={active}`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const properties = {search: true, social: false, menu: true, login: false};

const whatYouNeed = Object.keys(properties).reduce((acc,val) =>acc + (properties[val]? `${val} ` : '') ,'').trim();

console.log(whatYouNeed);
```